# How to make Payara (Eclipse Payara Tools) update all/stale files?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, payara

I am coding in Eclipse (Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) Build id: 20190917-1200) and using Payara Tools (1.0.0.201909271753) to manage the local Payara Server (5.201 #badassfish (build 512)).

The project is quite extensive and uses multiple libraries; Eclipse Java Projects and .jar-Files.
It also has 85 WebServlet classes. It basically all works really fine, with one exception:

I have a WebServlet class called 'DbMerge'

```
@WebServlet("/dyn/db/merge/dbmerge")
public class DbMerge extends HttpServlet {
    @Override protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest pReq, final HttpServletResponse pResp) throws IOException {
        final HttpConnector c = new HttpConnector();
        c.printNews();
    }
}
```

and another Class, called HttpConnector:

```
public class HttpConnector {
    public void printNews() {
        System.out.println("News 1");
        // System.out.println("News 2"); // comment in later
    }
}
```

When I deploy the Dynamic Web Project (right-click on prohect -> Debug as -> Debug on Server) it deploys properly, no problems.

When I change code in DbMerge, Payara Tools automatically and properly uplaods that change to the Payara Server. When I access `/dyn/db/merge/dbmerge` via browser on the server, I always get the correct up-to-date behaviour of DbMerge itself.

When I change code in some Java Project library or in the Class HttpConnector, that lies in the exact same package/directory as DbMerge, Payara Tools stills tells me it's Republishing for a while. (Eclipse Server view goes from `[Started, Synchronized]` to `[Started, Republish]` to `[Started, Synchronized]`).

BUT: when I access `/dyn/db/merge/dbmerge` again in the Browser, the code change in HttpConnector (or other classes in libraries) does NOT take effect. I have to 'restart' or re-deploy the project in order for those changes to take effect.

In this example, I do:

1. Deploy the project
2. Access `/dyn/db/merge/dbmerge` => Log shows "News 1"
3. Comment-in the second line (News 2)
4. Eclipse/Payara Tools refresh
5. I clear log
6. When I access `/dyn/db/merge/dbmerge`: log only shows a new "News 1", when it should show "News 1" and "News 2"

I assume that it's some kind of runtime optimization that loads classes only once, and only re-loads classes that are of type HttpServlet or annotated with @WebServlet and get accessed after a 're-publish'

So how do I get Eclipse / Payara Tools / Payara Server to also update those other stale files for development?

**UPDATE**

I found out that if I write `public class HttpConnector extends HttpServlet` (even though HttpConnector SHOULD NOT BE a HttpServlet) and completely re-deploy the project, THEN it will always keep that file up-to-date and always produce the expected behaviour.
If I deploy without 'extends' and add that later (only republish) it will not work.

**Update 2**

Looks like there's a caching bug in Payara. I have to completely stop and restart Payara, THEN deploy my project with `class HttpConnector extends HttpServlet` already in place, then it works.

If I un-deploy the project and re-deploy (or just 'restart' it from Eclipse Servers view), the effect of `class HttpConnector extends HttpServlet` will not work, contents will stay stale. So the first deployment seems to be the critical part, later un-deploys and deploys will not affect that anymore...

Answer (score 1):

There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1388) about a question along similar lines as yours on the Payara GitHub repository. It addresses reloading configuration files while deployed. Basically there are some third party options for development environment for reloading such as [JRebel](https://www.jrebel.com/products/jrebel), but nothing really for a deployment environment. From the sound if it, Payara are also not planning to work on such a feature either.

Quoting Mikecroft, a Senior Consultant at RedHat:

> Hi @edilmar - hot reloading has been addressed by #886 as @lprimak
> mentioned. This isn't a feature we're looking to add, since it's
> already satisfied by JRebel, but this is not a product to be used in
> production. ZeroTurnaround put significant effort into creating an
> equivalent that would work in production called LiveRebel, but
> discontinued it shortly after launch..
>
> Rolling upgrades will give you the zero downtime that you need or, if
> you wanted to move to a more modern container-driven deployment style,
> there are third party tools which will allow you to achieve the same
> thing with docker.
>
> I'll close this now, since it's not something we are going to pursue.

Comment: Yes. Thing is, there IS already some form of hot/re-deploy going on in the Payara Server. Whenever I save changes in Eclipse, ANY changed file gets uploaded, but only files tagged with @WebServlet at first deploy will get hot-replaced. Does not restart the project, keeps static content as is. But files not tagged with WebServlet at first deploy (or even tagged later) do not get updated, even if normal hot replace (like changes to non-static content in Eclipse in debug mode) should work. So I assume there's a bug with some loading optimization on the Payara side. You'll get bounty if no+answer

Comment: Ah ok... to not mess up how stackoverflow works, I assigned you the bounty but retracted the accepted answer. Because this is more or less still open.